# cookie is not set while on click of close button of popup

Tags: jquery, nopcommerce

I have write this code for open popup box. Code is below mention. I have set cookie so that it open one time only. I have problem while i click on close button cookie is not set for the popup so that it reopen every time.

```
<div id="abcPopup">
    <div id="popup-title">
       Hello
    </div>
    <div id="description">

    </div>
    <div id="picture">

    </div>

    <span style="display: none;" id="notification"></span>        
</div>
```

My Jquery Code is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var pageVisitedcookiesValue = getCookie("page_visited");
        if (pageVisitedcookiesValue == null || pageVisitedcookiesValue != "true") {
            var pageVisited;
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#abcPopup").dialog({
                    show: { effect: 'fade', duration: 450 },
                    hide: { effect: 'fade', duration: 450 }
                });
            }, 3000);            
            $('.ui-button-icon-only').click(function () {

                pageVisited = true;
                document.cookie = "page_visited" + "=" + pageVisited + ";" + "path=/";
            });
        }
    });

function getCookie(c_name) {
        var c_value = document.cookie;
        var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
        if (c_start == -1) {
            c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        }
        if (c_start == -1) {
            c_value = null;
        }
        else {
            c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
            var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if (c_end == -1) {
                c_end = c_value.length;
            }
            c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start, c_end));
        }
        return c_value;
    }
```

Now i ahve problem only occur while i set time out for open dialog box my onclick event is not capture while close popup box on close button click.

I have put alert box for same but its button click is not even fire or get so alert is happen but while i will remove set time out function my popup works fine. even its catch alert on close button also.

please guide for same.

Answer (score 2):

You're binding the `click` event immediately, but using `setTimeout` to create the dialog. So there's no `.ui-button-icon-only` element when you bind the handler.

One solution is to create the dialog immediately, but use `autoOpen: false`, and then open the dialog in the `setTimeout`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var pageVisitedcookiesValue = getCookie("page_visited");
    if (pageVisitedcookiesValue == null || pageVisitedcookiesValue != "true") {
        var pageVisited;
        $("#abcPopup").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: { effect: 'fade', duration: 450 },
            hide: { effect: 'fade', duration: 450 }
        });
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#abcPopup").dialog("open");
        }, 3000);            
        $('.ui-button-icon-only').click(function () {

            pageVisited = true;
            document.cookie = "page_visited" + "=" + pageVisited + ";" + "path=/";
        });
    }
});
```

Another solution would be to use event delegation.

```
$(document).on("click", ".ui-button-icon-only", function() {
    pageVisited = true;
    document.cookie = "page_visited" + "=" + pageVisited + ";" + "path=/";
});
```